# How to retrieve logged user id in flask?

Tags: python, api, authentication, flask, blueprint

I'm trying to make a web application with login functionality. After successful login, the user should add their request to the database with a SQL command:

```
db.execute(
            'INSERT INTO dailyLeave (dLeaveDateStart, dLeaveDateEnd, dComment, pId) '
            'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            (dLeaveDateStart, dLeaveDateEnd, dComment, pId)
```

But I need a user `id` to put it as pId in the database. How can I get logged user `id` ?

They are in separate blueprints (APIs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `Id` in session when the user logs in. Then you can retrieve it from the session.

First, you need to ensure that secret key is set at beginning of your Flask instance like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'any random string’
...
```

When user logs in:

> session['id'] = id

When you want to retrieve `id`, use session like python dictionary:

> pId = session['id']

When user logs out:

> session.pop('id')

Comment: can I use this session['id'] in different blueprints and python files in my project?

Comment: You can use it across whole flask application. Just import session from flask.